# How to set authentication in post request?

Tags: java, http

I have this, code which does a post request from an xml (soap) file

```
public static SoapEnv doRequest(String  url, String requestPath) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String requestBody = inputStreamToString(new FileInputStream(new File(requestPath)));
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(url))
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
        .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    SoapEnv value = xmlMapper.readValue(response.body(), SoapEnv.class);
    return value;
}
```

and it works.

But now I need to add basic authentication. I have login and password.

How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) should help. Just add `.header("Authorization" "Basic " + encodedcredentials)` to your builder chain, where `encodedcredentials` is the authorization string encoded as per the linked article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a header with the Base64 encoded authentication credentials separated by a colon ":".

Something like this;

```
    String auth = "username:password";
    String base64Creds = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(url))
        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds)
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
        .build();
```

Comment: I missed the comma, the colon is described in the auth string already, as it needs to be part of the encoded string. Thanks for pointing out the mistake! :)